# Whats the image size to keep in list view of size 70x70 in android

Tags: android-listview, android-imageview, android

I have the listview with each row have an image on left side and text on right side. I have the xml as shown in below.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivMenuListImage"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"/>
```

I have given the **Height** and **Width** as **70x70** and the Images are in higher pixels than this. The list view is displaying well. Now i dont want to use hardcode value. So i gave **width** and **height** as **wrapcontent** and resized the images as 70x70. But the images are looking very blured and image quality is very poor. Please help me.

Comment: While resizing make you don't compromise with image quality. Use a better tool which resize the image with good image quality

Comment: thanks Brijesh Thakur and one more help what should be the image resolution for ldpi,hdpi,and others?

Answer (score 1):

If your image does not have higher resolution you may need to set

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

in order not to stretch the image.

**Update:**
If you wish the row to appear "larger" on higher dpi devices, first you 1) set all your views' layout_height to `wrap_content` 2)Create png images with fixed width/height pixels for different density drawable folders. For example, in drawable-mdpi all your png images should have fixed height 70 pixel, then all the rows will appear to be 70dp high in mdpi devices. If you create images of height 96 pixel in hdpi folder, then all hdpi devices will look wider with 96dp height.

Comment: Is the above imageview the only view in your xml?

Comment: I believe you use LinearLayout as parent layout? You can set the height of that linearlayout as 70dp, then set the height of child imageview and textview as match_parent.

Comment: Just for clarifiation, In that case, in higher resolution bigger screen mobiles, the row height will be too small right?